# Inequation $\sqrt{(x-1)(x-2)} + \sqrt{(x-1)(x-3)} \geq 2\sqrt{(x-1)(x-4)}$

Tags: inequality

I need some help solving an inequation. So far I've factorized the polynomial:

$\sqrt{(x-1)(x-2)} + \sqrt{(x-1)(x-3)} \geq 2\sqrt{(x-1)(x-4)}$

Now what should I do to move forward?

Comment: Can you share the original question ?

Comment: That's the original question, just without the factorization part

Comment: Splitting into cases and Dividing by $\sqrt{x-1}$, after that try squaring the inequation.

Comment: @Luke, you're assuming $\sqrt{x-1}$ exists which might not be the case.

Comment: @Luke , Squaring the inequation might be in-appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the square roots to be defined, we need $x\leq 1$ or $x \geq 4$.

If $x \leq 1$, then

$$x-4<x-3<x-2<x-1\leq 0$$

and from here:

$$(x-4)(x-1)\geq (x-3)(x-1)\geq (x-2)(x-1)\geq 0$$

Therefore:

$$2\sqrt{(x-4)(x-1)}\geq \sqrt{(x-1)(x-2)}+\sqrt{(x-1)(x-3)}$$

Equality is possible only if $(x-4)(x-1)= (x-3)(x-1)=(x-2)(x-1)$, which implies $x=1$.

If $x \geq 4$, the equation is equivalent with:

$$\sqrt{x-1}\left(\sqrt{x-2}-\sqrt{x-4}\right)+\sqrt{x-1}\left(\sqrt{x-3}-\sqrt{x-4}\right)\geq 0$$

or (because the pair of square roots in the denominator can not be zero at the same time)

$$\sqrt{x-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{x-4}}+\sqrt{x-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-3}+\sqrt{x-4}}\geq 0$$

Since the square root is non-negative, this is obviously true for any $x$. Thus $\boxed{x\in \{1\} \cup [4,\infty)}$.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}&\sqrt{(x-1)(x-2)}+\sqrt{(x-1)(x-3)}\ge2\sqrt{(x-1)(x-4)}\\ 
&\Updownarrow\\
&\begin{cases}(x\le 1\lor x\ge2)\land(x\le 1\lor x\ge3)\land(x\le1\lor x\ge4)\\\sqrt{(x-1)(x-2)}+\sqrt{(x-1)(x-3)}\ge2\sqrt{(x-1)(x-4)}\end{cases}\\ 
&\Updownarrow\\
&\begin{cases}x\le1\lor x\ge4\\(x-1)(x-2)+(x-1)(x-3)+2\sqrt{(x-1)^2(x-3)(x-2)}\ge4(x-1)(x-4)\end{cases}\\ 
&\Updownarrow\\
&\begin{cases}x\le1\lor x\ge4\\2\sqrt{(x-1)^2(x-3)(x-2)}\ge(x-1)(2x-11)\end{cases}\\ 
&\Updownarrow\\
&\begin{cases}x\le1\lor x\ge4\\ (x-1)(2x-11)\ge0\\4(x-1)^2(x-3)(x-2)\ge(x-1)^2(2x-11)^2\end{cases}\lor \begin{cases}x\le1\lor x\ge4\\ (x-1)(2x-11)<0\end{cases}\\ 
&\Updownarrow\\
&\begin{cases}x\le1\lor x\ge4\\ x\le 1\lor x\ge\frac{11}2\\(x-1)^2(4x^2-20x+24-4x^2+44x-121)\ge0\end{cases}\lor \begin{cases}x\le1\lor x\ge4\\ 1<x<\frac{11}2\end{cases}\\ 
&\Updownarrow\\
&\begin{cases}x\le 1\lor x\ge\frac{11}2\\(x-1)^2(24x-97)\ge0\end{cases}\lor 4\le x<\frac{11}2\\ 
&\Updownarrow\\
&\begin{cases}x\le 1\lor x\ge\frac{11}2\\x=1\lor x\ge\frac{97}{24}\end{cases}\lor 4\le x<\frac{11}2\\ 
&\Updownarrow\\
&x=1\lor x\ge\frac{11}2\lor 4\le x<\frac{11}2\\ 
&\Updownarrow\\ &x=1\lor x\ge4
\end{align}